# How to set up custom intent filter

Tags: android

I'm trying to build an intent filter for a custom intent

```
registerReceiver(new CustomReceiver(), new IntentFilter("CUSTOM_INTENT"));
```

Here is `CustomReceiver`class

```
public class CustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

When I test the receiver

```
adb -s 24da2d85 shell am broadcast -a CUSTOM_INTENT
```

I get no response

```
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `new IntentFilter("CUSTOM_INTENT")` you define an action of *CUSTOM_INTENT* while sending an action of *android.intent.action.CUSTOM_INTENT*.

Better define an action in your own namespace

```
registerReceiver(new CustomReceiver(), new IntentFilter("my.action.CUSTOM_INTENT"));
```

and call it like

```
adb -s 24da2d85 shell am broadcast -a my.action.CUSTOM_INTENT
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting the same response `result=0`

Comment: Do I have to root my device to catch custom actions?

Comment: @the_prole I don't think this will ever change. It's the `resultCode` and 0 means no error. Put a log statement in `CustomReceiver.onReceive()` and see what happens there.

Comment: @the_prole you don't need to root your device to catch simple broadcasts.

Comment: Question: will my broad cast receiver remain active after I close the app, and after I reboot my phone?

Comment: @the_prole no. You habe to define it in the manifest instead.